# How can i make space between tags in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio

the nested tags are very close when closed and It confuses me , I want to make space between them. how can i?

[image]

Comment: "space" as in, a literal space? Or a newline?

Answer (score 0):

1. At the bottom you'll see `spaces: x`, Click on it.

[image: Here you can see it.]

2. On the opened window click on the `Indent Using Tabs`.

[image]

3. Change the number as you wish, a bigger number means bigger spaces. Good luck!

[image]